# "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT."

Tags: laravel

Estoy creando un proyecto para el cual cloné de git-hub el blog : milon / laravel-blog. Todo bien, funciona genial, pero está en inglés y mi sitio ha de poder traducirse al castellano y catalán. Instalé el paquete dimsav/laravel-translatable y mcamara/laravel-localization. En el archivo de rutas se han de poner todas las rutas dentro de:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale(),'middleware' => [ 'localeSessionRedirect', 'localizationRedirect', 'localeViewPath' ]], function(){
Route::get('/', 'BlogController@index');
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'BlogController@post');
Route::post('/posts/{post}/comment', 'BlogController@comment')->middleware('auth'); 
Auth::routes(); 
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('/posts', 'PostController');
    Route::put('/posts/{post}/publish', 'PostController@publish')->middleware('admin');
    Route::resource('/categories', 'CategoryController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('/tags', 'TagController', ['except' => ['show']]);
    Route::resource('/comments', 'CommentController', ['only' => ['index', 'destroy']]);
    Route::resource('/users', 'UserController', ['middleware' => 'admin', 'only' => ['index', 'destroy']]);
});});
```

Y aquí viene el problema, si las rutas están fuera del grupo de rutas para la traducción, funciona correctamente, pero al ponerlo dentro, por ejemplo la función que publica los posts me arroja el error:

"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PUT."

El código que realiza la petición es este:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2>
                        Posts

                        <a href="{{ url('admin/posts/create') }}" class="btn btn-default pull-right">{!! trans ('web.Create_New') !!}</a>
                    </h2>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.title') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.body') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.author') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.Category') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.Tags') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.Published') !!}</th>
                                <th>{!! trans ('web.Action') !!}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @forelse ($posts as $post)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit($post->body, 60) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $post->user->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $post->category->name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $post->tags->implode('name', ', ') }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $post->published }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if (Auth::user()->is_admin)
                                            @php
                                                if($post->published == trans ('web.yes')) {
                                                    $label = trans ('web.Draft');
                                                } else {
                                                    $label = trans ('web.publish');
                                                }
                                            @endphp

                                            <a href="{{ url("/admin/posts/{$post->id}/publish") }}" data-method="PUT" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-confirm="{{trans ('web.are_you_sure')}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning">{{ $label }}</a>
                                        @endif
                                        <a href="{{ url("/admin/posts/{$post->id}") }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success">{!! trans ('web.show') !!}</a>
                                        <a href="{{ url("/admin/posts/{$post->id}/edit") }}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info">{!! trans ('web.edit') !!}</a>
                                        <a href="{{ url("/admin/posts/{$post->id}") }}" data-method="DELETE" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" data-confirm="{{trans ('web.are_you_sure')}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">{!! trans ('web.delete') !!}</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @empty
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5">{!! trans ('web.No_post_available') !!}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforelse
                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                    {!! $posts->links() !!}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Tampoco entiendo como si no está dentro de un form puede realizar la acción... pues intenté ponerlo dentro de form y añadir la recomendación de los inputs hidden con el _method:put que aconsejan en la docu de laravel... pero no lo conseguí.

Comment: Antes de que empieces con una mala practica, a las rutas asignarles un name y al llamarlas usa `route()` en lugar de `url`. Respecto a tu error, habría que ver como estas gestionando el  data-method y  data-token, que es lo que te esta dando errores.

Comment: Estás accediendo mediante GET a una ruta que no lo es. Vete a tu web.php y haz una traza de la ruta que te retorna ese error ya verás que no es get. Puede que sea Post y para acceder a ella debas de venir desde un formulario que en el Action lleva dicha ruta.

Comment: ¿que version de laravel es esta?

Comment: Esto era un proyecto clonado de GitHub en Laravel 5.5 creo. Ya está mas que pasado.